# Illustrator Script: Export Single Layer to SVG

Tags: javascript, svg

I have been trying to get a script going that is able to export a specific illustrator file to a SVG format. I have been referencing [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20459/how-to-export-illustrator-layers-as-individual-images) Adobe forum post about a method of doing this and implemented it somewhat succesfully, see below:

```
    var singleLayer,
    doc,
    path = 'C:/Users/lukeb/Desktop/New folder',
    type = ExportType.SVG,
    options = new ExportOptionsSVG(),
    layerAmount;

doc = this.myApp;
singleLayer = this.myApp.layers["buttons"];
options.embedRasterImages = false;
options.cssProperties = SVGCSSPropertyLocation.PRESENTATIONATTRIBUTES;
options.fontSubsetting = SVGFontSubsetting.None;
options.documentEncoding = SVGDocumentEncoding.UTF8;
options.coordinatePrecision = 4;
layerAmount = doc.layers.length;

hideAllLayers();
for (var i = layerAmount - 1, k = 0; i >= 0; i--, k++) {
    if (this.myApp.layers[i] === singleLayer) {
        var file;

        singleLayer.visible = true;
        file = new File(path + "/" + singleLayer);
        this.myApp.exportFile(file, type, options);
        singleLayer.visible = false;
    }
}
showAllLayers();

function hideAllLayers() {
    for(var i = 0; i < layerAmount; i++) {
        doc.layers[i].visible = false;
    }
}

function showAllLayers() {
    for(var i = 0; i < layerAmount; i++) {
        doc.layers[i].visible = true;
    }
}
```

This code runs perfectly, to an extent. It singles out the layer in my layer library and turns all of them off except that one. But for some reason it does not export just that one layer as an SVG, it exports a whole lot, if not all of them. Is there something missing with this? There isnt a lot of documentation around all of this so wasnt too sure of a fool proof solution to just get a single layer.

Comment: Hiding layers probably doesn't stop them being exported. It just turns them off. A quick web search found this: https://github.com/iconic/illustrator-svg-exporter Does that help?